# How do I get one attribute from a main GUI into a second GUI within the code?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title="Space Game.py"
root.geometry=("1000x1000+500+300")
class Space(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        **self.MetalResource = 1000000
        self.CrystalResource = 1000000
        self.GasResource = 1000000**
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="#999999")
        self.grid()
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.Metal = Label(self, text="Metal", width=10, bg="#99CCFF")
        self.Metal.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.MetalValue = Label(self, text=self.MetalResource, width=10, bg="#99CCFF")
        self.MetalValue.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.Crystal = Label(self, text="Crystal", width=10, bg="#99CCFF")
        self.Crystal.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.CrystalValue = Label(self, text=self.CrystalResource, width=10, bg="#99CCFF")
        self.CrystalValue.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.Gas = Label(self, text="Gas", width=10, bg="#99CCFF")
        self.Gas.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.GasValue = Label(self, text=self.GasResource, width=10, bg="#99CCFF")
        self.GasValue.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.MetalMine = Button(self, text="Metal Mine", width=10, comman=self.MetalMineGUI, bg="#0000FF", fg="#FFFFFF")
        self.MetalMine.grid(row=5, column=4)

        self.MetalStorage = Button(self, text="Metal Storage", width=20, bg="#0000FF", fg = "#FFFFFF")
        self.MetalStorage.grid(row=5, column=2)

    def MetalMineGUI(self):
        root2 = Tk()
        root2.title="Beginner Level"
        root2.geometry=("400x400+500+300")
        class MetalMineGUI(Frame):
            def __init__(self, master):
                self.Level = 0
                Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="#3399FF")
                self.grid()
                self.pack()
                self.create_widgets()

            def create_widgets(self):
                if self.Level == 0:
                    a = "Build"
                    Metal = 500
                    Crystals = 250
                    Gas = 100
                else:
                    a ="Upgrade"
                    Metal = 500*self.Level
                    Crystals = 250*self.Level
                    Gas = 100*self.Level
                self.Upgrade = Button(self, text=a, width=10, command=self.Upgrade, bg="#99FFFF")
                self.Upgrade.grid(row=3, column=5)

                self.Details = Label(self, text="Details", width=30, bg="#3399FF")
                self.Details.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

                self.level = Label(self, text="Level", width=5, bg="#3399FF")
                self.level.grid(row=1, column=4)

                self.lvl = Label(self, text=self.Level, width=5, bg="#3399FF")
                self.lvl.grid(row=1, column=5)

                self.Need = Label(self, text="Need:", width=10, bg="#3399FF")
                self.Need.grid(row=2, column=1)

                self.MetalNeeded = Label(self, text=Metal, width=10, bg="#3399FF")
                self.MetalNeeded.grid(row=2, column=2)

                self.CrystalsNeeded = Label(self, text=Crystals, width=10, bg="#3399FF")
                self.CrystalsNeeded.grid(row=2, column=3)

                self.GasNeeded = Label(self, text=Metal, width=10, bg="#3399FF")
                self.GasNeeded.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=2)

            def Upgrade(self):
                self.Level+=1
                **self.MetalResource-=Metal
                self.CrystalResource-=Crystals
                self.GasResource-=Gas**

        app = MetalMineGUI(root2)
        root.mainloop()

app = Space(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Trying to get the self.MetalResource, the self.CrystalResource and the self.GasResource to be taken into account when the Build/Upgrade button is clicke. But when it is clicked it says that MetalMineGUI ahs now attribute self.MetalResource.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `MetalResource`, `CrystalResource` and `GasResource` are properties of the `Space` class, not the `MetalMineGUI` class and the `MetalMineGUI` has no reference to the `Space` class.

You defined the class like so

```
class OuterClass():

    def my_method(self):

        class InnerClass():
            pass
```

I'm not sure what you intended by this, but I don't see any reason that you would need to do this. Instead try something like

```
class Space(Frame):
    ...

class MetalMineGui(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, space):
        self.space = space
        ...

    def Upgrade(self):
        self.space.MetalResource -= Metal
        ...
```

Also as written, Metal isn't defined in the `Upgrade` function's scope. So you'll want to move the cost calculations into the `Upgrade` function or something similar.